# Has networking between Windows and Mac computers been improved in Snow Leopard?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard

When Leopard was launched it essentially broke the tight networking capability with Windows computers that Tiger had. Has anyone see this issue rectified on Snow Leopard?

In other words will I see my Windows computers at times and at times I won't (in Finder)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like Snow Leopard improved Samba networking, but I can't find anything specific about what changed.

In the meantime [here](http://www.macwindows.com/leopard.html#102907f) are some of the known fixes for Leopard (10.5) Samba networking.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, SMB networking with Windows computers seems much faster than before, especially when connection to shares.